# How to change Delphi 6 soap agent 1.1 to Soap agent 1.2?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-6

I am using Delphi 6 to develop a web service client. The service provider insists to use soap 1.2 . But when I checked THttpRio component in my Delphi 6 , I could see the soap agent is 1.1. How can I get soap agent 1.2 for delphi 6 ?

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards
Sinu

Comment: IIRC Soap 1.2 was added in Delphi 2010 - see http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2009/08/rad-studio-2010-soap-12.html